# Animate text area to fit the contents of the text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to resize the textarea to fit the contents of the text area.

I am currently using the following code to do that:

```
var element = document.getElementById(event.target.id);
var content = $(this).val().trim();

if (content == "") {
    $(this).animate({
        width: element.scrollWidth,
        height: element.scrollHeight
    }, 100);
}
```

When I enter nothing. I expect the textarea to become smaller in size and eventually disappear.

But it is expanding instead. :(

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7vfjet1g/

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle? They always help.

Comment: can you provide html code?

Comment: Added a jsfiddle link to the question

Comment: why are you animating scroll dimensions if you want it to disappear? Expected behavior could use some clarification

Comment: What field will contain the current width of the textarea?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is an elastic text area. There are a few JavaScript libraries that provide this functionality:

https://github.com/chemerisuk/better-elastic-textarea

https://github.com/chrisgeo/elastic-textarea

http://unwrongest.com/projects/elastic/

It's not much code, but a careful combination of JavaScript and CSS. If for some reason you don't want to add another library to your project, or this doesn't fit your requirement, it may point you in the right direction. Good luck.

Comment: I need something similar, but with the animation as shown in the jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0):

I tested out your existing code, and the values that scrollWidth and scrollHeight were giving you were much bigger than the size of the actual text.

One way to get the size of the actual text is to create a span with the same font styling as the text area, copy over the value of the textarea to it, then append the span to the document. You can then use getBoundingRect() to get the dimensions of the span, and thus the dimensions of the text in your textarea.

NOTE: I changed the id of your enclosing div. It had the same id as the textarea, and ids are supposed to be unique. Having two elements with the same id could cause problems with the javascript. Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yog8kvx7/7/. And here's the updated blur function:

```
$('.notesArea').blur(function (event)
{
    var content = $(this).val().trim();
    var element = document.getElementById(event.target.id);
    // Create span to calculate width of text
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    // Set position to absolute and make it hidden
    // so it doesn't affect the position of any other elements
    span.style.position = 'absolute';
    span.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    // Only set to whitespace to pre if there's content
    // "pre" preserves whitespace, including newlines
    if (element.value.length > 0)
        span.style.whiteSpace = 'pre-wrap';
    // Copy over font styling
    var fontStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element);
    span.style.display = 'inline-block';
    span.style.padding = fontStyle.padding;
    span.style.fontFamily = fontStyle.fontFamily;
    span.style.fontSize = fontStyle.fontSize;
    span.style.fontWeight = fontStyle.fontWeight;
    span.style.lineHeight = fontStyle.lineHeight;
    span.innerHTML = element.value;
    // Add to document and determine width
    document.body.appendChild(span);
    var rect = span.getBoundingClientRect();
    var width = rect.width;
    var height = rect.height;

    // Remove span from document
    span.parentNode.removeChild(span);

    $(this).animate({
        width: width,
        height: height
    }, 100);
});
```

And if you want to account for the little sizing handle, so it doesn't cover the text, you can just add an offset to the width to account for it.

Comment: This is not working as expected when the I am entering a lot of text.

Comment: Update answer. Using display inline-block for better sizing, and also correctly copying over font properties.